# Error using rotativa to convert hamlet to pdf

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, view, controller, rotativa

I have checked through the possible solution to this problem but I still get the same result may be am doing something wrong.
When I try to generate a pdf from html I get a red line this obviously indicates an error, this is my code controller method

```
Public ActionResult genHtmlToPdf(){
    var pdf= new ActionAsPdf("index");
    return pdf;
}
```

I get a redline on `ActionAsPdf` 
 Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to resolve the issue since my last post, it is alway necssary to add the reference on the reference tree in your project, while you think that the ref is added from nugget package manage when first add it you will need to confirm that it is truly added else your conversion will not work. Also get the rotativa compatible with your entity framework, hope this help
 Try using
 Rotativa.MVC
Add the ref to the using part of your project.
 Then try this
return new viewAsapdf("view name")